# AS3 How to declare an object without the dreaded "Conflict Exists" error?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, flash-cs5.5

I am designing a simple game in Flash and have come across this error. I have no idea how to go about this in actionscript and would appreciate any help.

Basically, I have a switch statement which creates an object of different type depending on each case (as I would prefer not to duplicate the same ten lines of code for each case) and I am getting a "conflict exists with definition in namespace internal" compiler error and I think I understand why.

```
switch(power){
    case 1:
        var Pow:objectOne = new objectOne();
        break;
    case 2:
        var Pow:objectTwo = new objectTwo();
        break;
}
```

My question however is this - what is the proper way of going about this?

I initially thought of declaring the variable before the switch statement which results in an "implicit coercion of a value of type object(One/Two) to an unrelated type Class" error. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Disclaimer: My AS3 is a little rusty ;)

Of what type would the variable `Pow` be *after* the switch statement? `objectOne` or `objectTwo`? From the compiler's perspective `objectOne` and `objectTwo` could be totally different from each other (read: methods, fields,...)

So:
A) Keep variable name for both assignments but declare it before the switch-statement AND use a common base-type (`object`, `MovieClip`,...)
B) Have 2 different variables: `var PowOne: objectOne` and `var PowTwo: objectTwo`

I think option A would be preferable...

Comment: Declaring Pow as type MovieClip did the trick! Because there are 5 different types of objects, you have just successfully reduced my code by 50 lines :) Thank you my good sir!

Answer (score 6):

Aside from the compiler error you are experiencing, another problem here is that you are planning on using the `pow` variable later in your code, yet they are of different types. My suggestion is to use the benefits of Inheritance in OOP and create a base class that your two custom classes can inherit from. That way they are both technically of the same base type, while still giving you the freedom to customize each custom class, while keeping similar functionality in the base class.

Remember, OOP is here to always help you and is there to avoid issues like the one you have come across, but here is how I would do it, and I tested the following implementation in Flash CC 2014 and it compiled successfully:

Example .FLA:

```
var pow:BaseClass;
var power = 1;

switch(power){
    case 1:
        pow = new ObjectOne();
        break;
    case 2:
        pow = new ObjectTwo();
        break;
}

pow.whichObjectAmI();    // this will simply trace what object pow is
```

**Base Class**

```
package  {

    public class BaseClass {

        public function BaseClass() {
            // constructor code
        }

        public function whichObjectAmI() {
            trace("I am the base class");
        }

    }

}
```

**Object One**

```
package  {

    public class ObjectOne extends BaseClass {

        public function ObjectOne() {
            // constructor code
        }

        override public function whichObjectAmI() {
            trace("I am Object One!");
        }

    }

}
```

**Object Two**

```
package  {

    public class ObjectTwo extends BaseClass {

        public function ObjectTwo() {
            // constructor code
        }

        override public function whichObjectAmI() {
            trace("I am Object Two!");
        }

    }

}
```

You can always inherit from any of ActionScript's classes as well like MovieClip, Button, etc. And by doing so, you're adding custom functionality on top of their functionality so 1) you don't have to rebuild a bunch of functionality, and 2) giving you the chance to reuse their functionality while adding your own custom code!

Comment: The problem here exists with code duplication. There are 5 cases in the switch statement and therefore 5 classes which have to be defined that inherit (with no further implementations) but by declaring variable Pow as a common base-type (MovieClip) and later defining Pow to be of type Object1 or Object2 ect. in each different case, this code duplication is avoided

Comment: If it were stated in your post that you needed something as simple as variable of type MovieClip for each variable in the switch from the beginning, this would have been a non-issue. Yet you stated you **'have a switch statement which creates an object of _different_ type depending on each case'** which is why I stand by my answer. Less code doesn't always mean good code. Even if you create simple classes that extend from MovieClip now, rather than later, means that you will have to refactor less. Unless of course your code will _never, ever, ever,_ change.

Comment: The Objects are of **different** types. The base-type is the same. If I had been aware that a variable could be declared type MovieClip and later defined as another Object, I would not have asked the question. And even though less code does not equal good code, less duplication does equal good practice.

Comment: I agree that less duplication is a good practice, no argument there. Not having to refactor code is equally important, especially when the code we are talking about, the code I put together for you, only took a couple minutes to write and test. You're arguing over something that is there to help you improve your code, will require little refactoring later, and was _minimal_ effort to create. That's a win! Like I said though, which you seemed to have skipped over, if you are _never_ going to use any custom functionality then you are fine with what you have. Just trying to help. Cheers.

Comment: I did not mean to offend you. For this particular project I was certain there would be no custom functionality therefore I prefer the base-type solution however I will probably be making use of this code for future projects which either require additional functionality for separate classes or have less derived classes, so I did upvote your solution because this **was** very helpful. Thanks :)